# Can I travel to Croatia with single-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, croatia

I am traveling to Zurich with a single-entry Schengen visa.

While coming back can I travel to Croatia for 3 days and then return to India (Country of Origin)?

Answer (score 8):

Update, January 2023: This answer is no longer correct as Croatia has joined the Schengen area in full.

The original answer follows.

---

**No, you cannot.** Unfortunately the [Ministry of Foreign and European Affairs in Croatia](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/) clearly states that you need a multiple entry visa in order to do so.

> In line with the Government’s decision, aliens who are holders of:
>
> - uniform visa (C) for **two or multiple entries, valid for all Schengen Area member states**;
> - visa with limited territorial validity (LTV visa), for two or multiple entries, issued
>   to the holder of a travel document that is not recognised by one or more, but not all of
>   the Schengen Area member states, and which is valid for the territory of the member
>   states recognising the travel document;
> - long-stay visa (D) for stays exceeding three months, issued by one of the Schengen
>   Area member state;
> - residence permit issued by one of the Schengen Area member state;
>
> do not require a visa for transit through or intended stays in the
> territory of the Republic of Croatia not exceeding 90 days in any
> 180-day period.

I have traveled to Croatia from the Schengen area before and while doing so, you will obtain an exit stamp from the Schengen area (mine was from Slovenia) and then an entry stamp into Croatia.

While leaving, you will get an exit stamp from Croatia and an entry stamp into your next destination (mine was back into the Schengen area in Slovenia).

Until Croatia officially becomes a part of the Schengen area and lifts its border controls (scheduled for 2016), they have **instituted a policy of visa-free travel for Schengen visa holders, but this still requires you to enter and exit the Schengen area**.

[From Visit Croatia UK website](http://www.visit-croatia.co.uk/index.php/information-on-croatia/visa-requirements-for-croatia/),

> On joining the EU, Croatia extended a ruling for holders of Schengen
> visas that was first introduced in 2012. This regulation allows
> holders of Schengen visas to enter, stay and transit in or through
> Croatia WITHOUT the need for an additional visa (for tourist
> purposes). This ruling continues this year and is in effect from 1st
> January 2014 up until 31st December 2014.

Note that this visa free travel is valid until the end of 2014 but will likely be extended the same way it was extended in 2013 or 2012.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but please note that i am not re entering Schengen area but will fly back to my contry in that case Croatia might allow me to stay there and leave for my country

Comment: @Vadirajjoshi Please take a look at this [question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18420/can-i-apply-for-another-schengen-visa-when-i-already-have-a-single-entry-unused) as well, I'll also edit this answer in order to reflect your situation

Comment: Would a single-entry visa still be *valid* once you have an exit stamp? I have no idea if Croatian border guard are so meticulous but it's not obvious to me.

Comment: It wasn't completely obvious to me as well, which is why I took reference from jpatokal's answer in the question above. Also, from past experience, they are not meticulous about it. In fact one of my friends has a missing Croatian entry stamp on his passport. LOL. The guy who was letting him exit the country was super confused and kept asking him where is the stamp while showing him our passports. But he went thru just fine.

Comment: Some more nit-picking but I don't think it's required to actually leave Croatia through the Schengen area. What's required is to have the right to re-enter it, so to hold a multiple-entry visa or an unused single-entry visa. You could either enter from a non-Schengen country or leave to somewhere else (possibly not both in the same trip, though).

Comment: @Relaxed I found a link on the a ministry website. Turns out officially, jpatokal's answer would be wrong too. Well :/ I edited it The.Third.Time to reflect the right detail.

Comment: Also one more thing (I won't leave you alone!) Croatia is already part of the EU. But like two other countries (Bulgaria and Romania), it has to wait that the other members are satisfied with its implementation of the Schengen agreement before lifting border controls (“fully applies the provisions of the Schengen acquis” is the lingo).

Comment: @Relaxed Also, they won't let you travel even with an unused single entry visa in theory. In practice though, they don't seem to be too nit-picky about it.

Comment: @Relaxed Haha. Yes. Indeed you are right. Schengen not EU. :(

Comment: Also, since Romania and Bulgaria have been blocked for silly political reasons despite a positive opinion from the Commission, I am not confident Croatia will be able to become part of the Schengen area so soon :-( (their rules since January are modeled after the Romanian rules it seems).

Comment: @Relaxed Well dates are always tentative. ;)

Comment: "I am not confident Croatia will be able to become part of the Schengen area so soon" Oh noo.

Answer (score 7):

Aditya Somani's answer was correct when written, but as [Croatia has now joined the Schengen area](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-64144309), it is no longer up to date.

A Schengen visa is now unconditionally valid for travel to Croatia, as long as all other terms of the visa (e.g., limits on number of entries and on total duration of stay) are followed. Direct flights or land transit from other Schengen countries do not count as an additional "entry" anymore, so it is possible to enter another country in the Schengen area with a single-entry visa, and then fly or take the train to Croatia, as long as you do not pass through any non-Schengen countries while making the connection. You can then return to the originally visited country (or another Schengen country), or fly directly home from Croatia, as you prefer.

Comment: Nitpick: it's best not to use position to refer to answers, position can vary as votes are cast and some users may not select the default sort order.