# Is it possible to visit Croatia with a Single Entry Schengen Visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, croatia

What if I was granted with single entry schengen visa but I will not utilize it to enter any schengen state but only in Croatia, is it possible?.

I will pass only a schengen state as connecting flight going to Croatia e.g. from my origin country to Germany as my connecting to my flight to Croatia and then vice versa.

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: 100% duplicate of [Can I travel to Croatia with single-entry Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30736/can-i-travel-to-croatia-with-single-entry-schengen-visa)

Comment: Not a duplicate because OP in this case does not plan to use his Schengen visa for visiting Schengen

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder it is an Annex I nationality.  That's all we need to know.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do this.  A single-entry Schengen visa is [not valid for entry into Croatia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/30737/19400), regardless of whether or not it has been or will be used in the Schengen area.