# Schengen visa extension?

Tags: schengen, visa-extensions

I've got an existing multiple entry Schengen visa that I've applied through the German consulate as I was traveling to Germany 25/8, valid until 31st Oct. I've applied this visa with using my kids passport whose a British citizen.

I have now bought a ticket to Spain on 28/10 and back from Spain to UK on the 2nd of November. I will travelling with my British kids again. I'm trying to apply for another visa. But been told that I have to cancel my other Schengen visa and reapply to Spain for Schengen.

1.is there a possibility to extend

2. Can I just apply visa through the German consulate, as I've already had an existing visa and try to continue that, if that's the case, how would I do it?
   Thank you x

Comment: How long is your stay in Germany from start to finish? Is it 90 days? Is it a C visa? How long and why do you want to go to Spain?

Comment: I've been and gone from Germany, it was from 25th of August to 31st of August. But my partner have now bought us a holiday tickets to Spain for just a week at the end of Oct, from 28th October until 2nd of November. When I'm querying about having to get another visa .. there's no clear explanation. Would you be able to clarify for me please. X

Comment: What is a C visa, all I can gather is that my visa is a multiple entry x

Comment: If you have a ‘C’ type visa (ie short-term visa, see example here https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/visa-sticker/) and not a ‘D’ visa which is equivalent to a residential permit, it’s not normally possible to extend https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31164/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-tourist-schengen-visa-12-more-days

Comment: Ok I understand, what would I need to do with my previous visa, as it's valid until 31st Oct and I'm traveling from 28th until 2nd of Nov. I only need a couple of days to entitle me travel out and back in

Comment: Can I apply to German consulate as I can do it in Manchester and still travel to Spain?

Comment: @Masniari Hamonangan You can’t travel with your existing multiple entry visa after its expiry date. You either need to change your holiday dates to within the visa validity period or apply for a new visa to the Spanish Consulate (ie your destination country for the intended trip).

Answer (score 1):

Your visa will be expired and, I assume, you are out of the schengen area. You will now need to apply for a visa from the Spanish representation which serves your place of residence since that will be your main destination for that trip.

There is no possibility to extend a C type visa. You should apply soon to avoid any hassle. If you have a good travel history, the spanish representation should not have any reason to deny you.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing multiple entry Schengen visa is only valid for travel within the period up to and including 31 October. There is no easy way to extend it [Is it possible to extend a tourist Schengen visa (12 more days)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31164/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-tourist-schengen-visa-12-more-days)

To visit Spain you either need to change your travel dates to within the existing visa validity period or apply to the Spanish consulate for a new visa. You cannot apply to a different Consulate eg Germany, just because it’s more convenient.

My understanding is that you can’t hold overlapping visas but Spain can issue your new visa with a validity starting from 1 November [Apply new Schengen Visa while hold an valid one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51979/apply-new-schengen-visa-while-hold-an-valid-one) Since you have a multiple entry visa and have already used it for the purpose for which it was approved, it will be valid for your trip to Spain together with a new visa from Spain.

Comment: Do I need to cancel my existing visa

Comment: Ok. From my understanding, I can apply to Spanish consulate for a Spanish Schengen visa with my planned holiday that's been booked (I can't cancel this due to kids being in the school holiday) and still will be continuing from the 1st of November. They won't say that I will need to cancel the existing visa in order to get the new visa for my travel. Is this correct.